# Libzip - Error: Error while opening the archive : no error

Tags: c++, zip, compression, libzip

I'm trying to find out the solution to solve a problem;
In fact, i'm writing my own tool to make saves using libzip in C++ to compress the files.

Absolutly not finished but i wanted to make some tests, then i do and obtain a "funny" error from the log.

Here's my function:

```
void save(std::vector<std::string> filepath, std::string savepath){
int err;

savepath += time(NULL);
zip* saveArchive = zip_open(savepath.c_str(), ZIP_CREATE , &err);
if(err != ZIP_ER_OK) throw xif::sys_error("Error while opening the archive", zip_strerror(saveArchive));
for(int i = 0; i < filepath.size(); i++){
    if(filepath[i].find("/") == std::string::npos){}
    if(filepath[i].find(".cfg") == std::string::npos){
        err = (int) zip_file_add(saveArchive, filepath[i].c_str(), NULL, NULL);
        if(err == -1) throw xif::sys_error("Error while adding the files", zip_strerror(saveArchive));
    }

}

if(zip_close(saveArchive) == -1) throw xif::sys_error("Error while closing the archive", zip_strerror(saveArchive));
}
```

I get a `=> Error : Error while opening the archive : No error`
And, of course, i didn't have any .zip written.

If you could help me, thanks to you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.nih.at/libzip/zip_open.html) for `zip_open` says that it only sets `*errorp` if the open fails.  Either test for `saveArchive == nullptr` or initialize `err` to 
ZIP_ER_OK.

P.S.  The search for `'/'` does nothing.  Did you mean to put a `continue` in that block?

The other problematic line is:

```
    savepath += time(NULL);
```

If that is the standard `time` function, that returns a time in seconds since the epoch.  That will probably get truncated to a char, and then that char appended to the file name.  That will cause strange characters to appear in the filename!  I suggest using `std::chrono` to convert to text.

Comment: I didn't get this stupid "no error" anymore, but it doesn't create a .zip file too ...

The search for '/' is not implemented yet.

Thanks for reply.

Comment: Step through it in a debugger.  Is there anything in the vector?  What does add return?

Comment: I think that i didn't understand how zip_file_add works. Indeed, function doesn't compress and add my file to the archive but it makes just a path inside. Thanks for helping.